# Import Data From multiple sheet with a list of ID and specifics column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have about many spreadsheet work with my partners and each partner use 1 spreadsheat for manage data.
I using a table to store all ID, Sheet name and column store data I need to import to my master sheet.
This is my Spreadsheet:
[Link here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zvXkMBTAA2K6xu_CO1I47eMmT0g0W58ew_s5gh8D43Y/edit#gid=1588076901)
[image]

I using Appscript to do import data by read values in this table with 2 loop, I see it work to slow How could I speed up it?
this is my script

```
function myFunction() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Source Link');
var master = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Master') ;
const dstLr = getLastPopulatedRow(ss); //get last row of Source Link
const target_sheet_name = ss.getRange(2,6,dstLr-1,1).getValues(); //Get data in Column F input to array
const ids = ss.getRange(2,1,dstLr-1,1).getValues(); //get data in column A input to array
const ebayID = ss.getRange(2,2,dstLr - 1,1).getValues(); //get cloumn index at Column B input to array
const team = ss.getRange(2,3,dstLr-1,1).getValues(); //get column containt team name at column C input to array
const linkOrder = ss.getRange(2,4,dstLr-1,1).getValues(); //get cloumn containt Link Order at column D input to array
const tracking = ss.getRange (2,5,dstLr-1,1).getValues(); //get column containt Tracking at column E input to array
const benCO = ss.getRange(2,7,dstLr,1).getValues();

    ids.forEach((id, i) => {
      const srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(target_sheet_name[i]);
      const lr = getLastPopulatedRow(srcSheet);
      const srcCol = [ebayID[i], team[i], linkOrder[i],tracking[i]].flat();
          for(var j = 0; j < srcCol.length; j++) {
          const destCol = [1,2,3,4];
          const destCol2 = [5];
          destCols = destCol[j]
          const srcRange = srcSheet.getRange(3, srcCol[j], lr); // Origin range to copy
          const values = srcRange.getValues(); // Getting values from origin column
          const destRange = master.getRange(2, destCols, lr);
          master.clearContents;
          destRange.setValues(values);
        }
      
    })
}

function getLastPopulatedRow(sheet) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = data.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
      if (data[i][j]) return i+1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I also need add value of G column for each data I import from ID and Sheet name at colum A and column F, but when I try set value for column E at Master sheet I got error that "data have 1 but destination range have 582"
Could Some one give me advise

That's what I try

```
ids.forEach((id, i) => {
  const srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(target_sheet_name[i]);
  const lr = getLastPopulatedRow(srcSheet);
  const srcCol = [ebayID[i], team[i], linkOrder[i],tracking[i]].flat();
      for(var j = 0; j < srcCol.length; j++) {
      const destCol = [1,2,3,4];
      const destCol2 = [5];
      destCols = destCol[j]
      const srcRange = srcSheet.getRange(3, srcCol[j], lr); // Origin range to copy
      const values = srcRange.getValues(); // Getting values from origin column
      const destRange = master.getRange(2, destCols, lr);
      master.clearContents;
      destRange.setValues(values);
    }
  const coName = [];
  coName.push(benCO[i]);
  master.getRange(2,5,lr,1).setValues(coName);
})
```

and this is error:
[image]

Comment: I thought that in your script and your sample image, when the spreadsheet ID of the column "A" cannot be seen, the script cannot be tested. Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: Hi in my questtion I give link to my sample sheet too, this is it:" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zvXkMBTAA2K6xu_CO1I47eMmT0g0W58ew_s5gh8D43Y/edit#gid=1588076901

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't see your sample Spreadsheets of the spreadsheet ID of column "A". I apologize for this.

Comment: this is my company partner data, and it be set privated permission, I just only make copy 1 sheet at A2 here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jr7gDYwlBFKD9HoKlF23JZ6Sun0CuX6muEOMpIElBx4/edit#gid=916093439  and I can share you the copy of it

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and samples, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceLink = ss.getSheetByName('Source Link');
  const master = ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  const srcValues = sourceLink.getRange("A2:G" + sourceLink.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const header = ["Order ID", "Team", "ID", "ID TRACKING#"];
  const values = [header, ...srcValues.flatMap(r => {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(r[0]).getSheetByName(r[5]);
    const [, h, ...v] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    const temp = h.map(e => e.trim());
    const indexes = header.map(e => temp.indexOf(e));
    return v.map(r => indexes.map(i => r[i]));
  })];
  master.clearContents().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- In this sample script, first, the header is declared and the values are retrieved using the header from each sheet. And, the populated values are put into the destination sheet.
- In this sample script, the header is used from your sample Spreadsheet. So, when you change the header titles, the result values might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> I got messenger error at this line: const temp = h.map(e => e.trim()); messenger said: TypeError: e.trim is not a function

My proposed script is for your provided Spreadsheet, and when I tested my proposed script no error occurs. From your reply, I guessed that your Spreadsheet might be different from your provided Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, from your error message, I'm worried that the header rows might be changed. In your provided Spreadsheet, 1st 2 rows are header rows. But, if the header row is only the 1st row, the error might occur because the row values include the date object in the 2nd row. If my understanding is correct, can you test the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceLink = ss.getSheetByName('Source Link');
  const master = ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  const srcValues = sourceLink.getRange("A2:G" + sourceLink.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const header = ["Order ID", "Team", "ID", "ID TRACKING#"];
  const values = [header, ...srcValues.flatMap(r => {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(r[0]).getSheetByName(r[5]);
    // const [, h, ...v] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let h;
    let [h1, h2, ...v] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    if (h2.some(e => e instanceof Date)) {
      h = h1;
      v = [h2, ...v];
    } else {
      h = h2;
    }
    const temp = h.map(e => e.trim());
    const indexes = header.map(e => temp.indexOf(e));
    return v.map(r => indexes.map(i => r[i]));
  })];
  master.clearContents().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- If the same error occurs and another error occurs, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: But when I add more spreadsheet ID (about total 38 ID), script got "TypeError: e.trim is not a function", how can I fix it

Comment: and many data in "Order ID" not copy to master too

Comment: @HOANG TRUNG LE Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But when I add more spreadsheet ID (about total 38 ID), script got "TypeError: e.trim is not a function", how can I fix it` and `and many data in "Order ID" not copy to master too`. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: I add more value to sourcelink sheet and the script got error, you can check it by run script in this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zvXkMBTAA2K6xu_CO1I47eMmT0g0W58ew_s5gh8D43Y/edit#gid=0)

Comment: @HOANG TRUNG LE Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I add more value to sourcelink sheet and the script got error, you can check it by run script in this link`, I cannot know your current error message. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of `and the script got error`? Unfortunately, I cannot test your situation. I think that this is due to my poor skill.I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: Hi, my English skill bad too :). I got messenger error at this line:   **const temp = h.map(e => e.trim());**       messenger said:       **TypeError: e.trim is not a function**

Comment: @HOANG TRUNG LE By guessing your current situation, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If the same error occurs and another error occurs, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thank for your help, in new script all spreadsheet import to master correctly but just only one get error, this is sample sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KA9gLhmxWZH-CzUVVulzTlKxB28pK8vduouHY2ybhas/edit#gid=190718994

Comment: in Source Link Tab, this spreadsheet store at row 38

Comment: @HOANG TRUNG LE Thank you for replying. When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that the header title is different from your 1st provided Spreadsheet. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. And, I think that in this case, the question is a different question from your initial question. So, in this case, I would like to recommend resolving from your 1st provided Spreadsheet. And, from your reply, I cannot still know whether my proposed script resolved your 1st provided Spreadsheet. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @HOANG TRUNG LE And, I would like to support you. So, I would like to recommend posting your other Spreadsheet as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: OK I will make compled this question and will ask new for 2nd Spreadshet, thank you very much

Comment: I am glad to tell you that I found why it got error, there is on spreadsheet in my list got difrence tructure. I fixed